# Will the Shuttle Omninas KD20 wipe my data during initial setup?

Tags: hard-drive, nas, data-loss-prevention, jbod, shuttle

I have a new KD20 Omninas from Shuttle, and two hard drives full of pre-existing data I would like to share using it.

I was planning on selecting the JBOD (just a bunch of disks) RAID mode, and at first assumed that there would be no way they wouldn't warn you about potential data loss. However, the translation so far has been poor, and the title of the relevant page in the setup wizard "Create a RAID Disk" has me worried that it will wipe my existing data. (To me, "create" implies rewriting partition tables)

Does anyone have any experience with this particular NAS?

Thanks in advance!

[image: Page 5 of the OMNINAS Wizard]

Comment: If anyone knows a how to setup this NAS to share existing data in JBOD mode, I will gladly accept that as the correct answer since the information is much more valuable than the "yes, it will" I found in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will!! I found the full user manual online (I don't have a CD drive to read the one shipped with the device). Page 32 warns "The initialization process will erase all data from the hard drive". They might have wanted to give a heads up in the quick start guide!

[image: Page 32 of the User Manual]